# Please assist in confirming if my understanding of covariance here is correct?

Tags: c#, oop

I have been battling through covariance and contravariance for a few days now and I think I have understood something but I was hoping that I could get confirmation on this as I haven't been able to get a yes or no answer through my current research. I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Shape
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Square : Shape
{

}
```

Then, this is what I what I started off the program with:

```
List<Square> squares = new List<Square>() { new Square { Name = "Square One" }, new Square { Name = "Square Two" } };
IEnumerable<Square> squaresEnum = squares;
```

Now are the two questions I have:

Is the following possible because IEnumerable< T > IS covariant:

```
IEnumerable<Shape> shapesEnumerable = squares;
```

AND, is the following NOT possible because List< T > is NOT covariant:

```
List<Shape> shapes = squares;
```

Here is the full program code if it is required for anything:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Square> squares = new List<Square>() { new Square { Name = "Square One" }, new Square { Name = "Square Two" } };
        IEnumerable<Square> squaresEnum = squares;

        /* Does this work because IEnumerable<T> is covariant? */
        IEnumerable<Shape> shapesEnumerable = squares;

        /* Does this NOT work because List<T> is NOT covariant */
        //List<Shape> shapes = squares;

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
class Shape
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Square : Shape
{

}
```

Please could you let me know if I'm on the right track with this?

Comment: Yes; that is correct.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right track.

this code was not permissible, because we can have this difficulte situation.

We can create new class like ths:

> class Triangle : Shape { }

Then

```
IEnumerable<Shape> triangles = new List<Triangle>()
{ 
        new Triangle { Name = "Triangle One" }, 
        new Triangle { Name = "Triangle Two" } 
};
```

And now if this case can be permissible

```
List<Shape> squares = new List<Square> { ... };
```

We can develop like this

```
squares.AddRange(triangles);
```

or other issues like this.

The Net compiler is very clever :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case of covariance. `IEnumerable<T>` defines `T` as `out T`, so an `IEnumerable<Square>` can be assigned to `IEnumerable<Shape>`. The reason you can't do this with `List<T>` is that it is not an interface, and only interfaces can declare co- and contravariance.

Also, it does not make sense for `List<T>` to have `T` be covariant, as it is also used as an input, highlighted by the example given by Arlyom Tonoyan. `IEnumerable<T>` can define at as such since it is only used as output.